# How to use 3 <h:form/> tag in JSF in same line?

Tags: jsf

I am getting a scenerio where there are three buttons() right next to each other. They need to be enclosed by  tag to work properly. The problem here is out of 3 buttons, second button operation must open in new window, rest in same window. So I was forced to use 3  tag around 3 buttons respectively with second one having target="_blank" property set. However, each  starts with newline. I want all 3 buttons on same line with second button's form tag having property, target="_blank". Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because the HTML `<form>` element is by default a [**block** element](http://htmlhelp.com/reference/html40/block.html). HTML block elements are positioned in their own new line. Apart from putting them inside a table, you can also just display them **inline** using CSS. This way they won't be positioned in their own line, but next each other.

```
form {
    display: inline;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

wrap them around `<h:panelGrid columns="3">`

Then you will have each buttom in one colum, thus inline.

Answer (score 0):

Answer is simple.. Sometimes solution will be right in front of your eyes and we cant see it. Used table tag of simple HTML.